How to securely read and store password in memory in nodejs
I want to take a password from user in console, then derive a key from that password.
In Java, we can store passwords in a char array and zeroize the array after use.
What is the right way of doing this in nodejs where no extra copies of the password are created in memory and the password is garbage collected as soon as possible.
In simple terms, how to securely handle sensisitve data such as passwords and keys in a nodejs application?
(assume that I am making a cli desktop app entirely in nodejs and typescript/javascript without any 3rd party libraries)

Simply said, there is no absolutely secure way to do so. Because one time or the other you have to hold the sensitive information in the memory and that's the moment a malware could get hold of that information. With zeroing out after use you are just shortening the period of time where this can happen, and therefore lessen the chances.

But in principle you could of course apply the same mechanisms you do in Java. Ie instead of storing your information in an immuatable string and hope and wait for it to be garbage collected (which is also no guarantee it's actually deleted from memory), you can store your data into arrays and overwrite their content, when not needed anymore.

@derpirscher you’re right, my goal is just to minimise the time sensitive data stays in the memory, also, are char arrays possible in js?

There is no explicit char type. but you can of course store a string like "foobar" as ["f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r"] ie a bunch of strings, each of them holding a single character
